# Is there any way to stop the UI window instance of WPF

Tags: c#, http, xmlhttprequest, dotnet-httpclient

When I'm sending the data on a server and server is not up then I get an exception Unable to connect to the server and the UI window instance is closed while executing the line of code :
(response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("windows/actions", data).ConfigureAwait(false);). How can I stop the UI window it should not be closed.

My code :

```cs
        public static async void PostInfo(List<ElementProps> requestObj)
    {
    try
        {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
            // Setting Base address. 
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://126.1.1.1:8888/"); 

            // Setting content type.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            string list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObj); 
            object data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(list); 

            // HTTP POST ** Here is the error **
            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("windows/actions", data).ConfigureAwait(false); 

            // Verification
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            { 
                 System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Recording saved successfully!"); <br/>
            } 
        } 
    } 

    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         ErrorLog.Log(ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code in a more readable format (and without the unnecessary bold for the text of your question). See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for editing guidance.

Comment: Please next time copy code from a text editor, not a browser or the like. `<br/>` doesn't belong to code.

Comment: sure I will take care of that from next time. thnaks for suggestion @PMF

Comment: Your program should enter the catch block in this case. But you may not be on the UI thread any more because of `ConfigureAwait(false)`  and thus `MessageBox.Show` will probably fail.

Comment: No MessageBox.show not fails it will show the exception but I need to stop the UI window instance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My main thread exits before the http client async operation finishes.

I just add `.Wait()` to caller to maintain the main thread. So, I have this :

```
PostInfo(Records).Wait();
```

Comment: thanks @Elikill58 for editing my answer actually I am very new in stack overflow but why are you marked the answer is not useful? it resolved my problem so its useful for me according to my question.

Comment: I don't mark as not useful. If you are talking about thé downvote, it's not because of me